# TeeChart for .NET v2 on 64-bit OS - License Verification Issue

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I have installed TeeChart for .NET v2 on a fresh OS. When attempting to build an in-house client application dependent on TeeChart it fails with the license verification. The usual stuff:

> Exception occurred creating type 'Steema.TeeChart.TChart, TeeChart, Version=2.0.2586.24039, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8126276c77bdb7' System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The general support solution for this seems to be that the registry isn't properly set up, but the installer should have taken care of that... The key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Steema Software\TeeChart.NET\DesignKeyV2` has the value `Steema.TeeChart.TChart is a licensed component.` As far as I can tell, that is what should be checked...

I wonder if the problem is that it's a 64-bit OS and maybe the `WoW6432Node` bit is throwing off the license validation? But it sounds to me like the licx API is a Microsoft .NET solution so I'd assume it would know how to find the appropriate keys in the registry for the given platform...

I've tried configuring the project to target x86 specifically, but without success. It still fails to build with the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer through some investigating.. Hopefully this speeds up the process for the next guy. I think that the 64-bit registry does indeed end up being wrong for the license verification for whatever reason. Maybe something Steema is doing themselves... There is a tool in their "client access" area of their Web site [https://www.steema.com/clientaccess - you'll need your licensing information to login] that you can download called TeeRegV2 that will install the needed keys into the registry to get things working...

Comment: I must add that this is for TeeChart for .NET v2. New versions installers do this automatically without the need of the TeeRegister tool.